# UTF-8 Decode for php

Tags: php, utf-8, decoding

I am fetching posts from the Tumblr API and am running into an encoding issue with the returned "body" of the "post". All apostrophes are replaced by something that looks like "aETM".

I am trying to use:

```
utf8_decode($string)
```

But all that does is replace the occurrences of "aETM" with a "?".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string,'HTML-ENTITIES','utf-8');
```

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks. Can you explain why utf8_decode doesn't work?

Comment: utf8_decode converts UTF-8 strings to ISO-8859-1 (a.k.a. Latin1) strings.

Comment: @jrubins: It's because the character represented with that byte sequence does not exist in ISO-8859-1, which is what utf8_decode decodes to - so it generates a ? instead, which acts as a replacement character. If you had used UTF-8 all the way through (and you really, really should), there wouldn't have been any issue to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this link to convert string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $data)